# SSL installed on Lightsail Instance with Route53 Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

i am trying to install an SSL certificate.

I have a domain with Route53 and a Wordpress hosting setup with Lightsail. This tutorial told me to set up a DNS Zone:

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress

After doing so, my domain can no longer connect to my IP.

There are so many places to edit nameservers, it's hard to keep track.
Route53 has NS records under "Hosted Zones"... It also has some under "Registered Domains"...

I ran a WHOIS on the domain and they are retrieving the old nameservers I reverted back to before I created the Lightsail DNS Zone as instructed by the tutorial.
... and it still won't work.

I deleted the DNS zone I created through Lightsail to return to what was originally written in Route53... Returned the nameservers to the old values, and made sure the NS records under "Hosted Zones" match up with the nameservers in the "Registered Domains".

anyone wanna take a crack at this?

Comment: If you're just using Lets Encrypt for SSL, you didn't need to move any DNS settings to Lightsail. The steps it says to perform in the Lightsail DNS zone, you could just do in the Route53 zone instead.

Comment: Yeah, I just followed it as instructed. I didn't realize at the time so it's my mistake. However, after deleting the Lightsail DNS and reverting back to the old nameservers, it seems the domain still can't connect.

Comment: **"my domain can no longer connect to my IP"**. When you create the DNS record how did You test the DNS resolution ?... in a terminal (powershell or bash) you can run commands like: `nslookup mydomain.com`... or you can go to this [site](https://dnschecker.org/) and search for A record in your domain... depending of the result of these tests (waiting for DNS propagation time) you can isolate  the problem and give us more information...

Comment: It sounds like you did everything correctly. Try checking your domain here https://dnschecker.org/ to avoid any caching issues on your computer.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, you're correct. I didn't expect it to take so long as the TTL is set to 60 seconds. Everything is operational again, I hope my SSL is installed correctly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MarkB For some reason I can still access my /wp-admin folder over an insecure connection

Comment: @Matthew Unless you setup something to actually block or redirect insecure connections, both port 80 (unencrypted) and port 443 (encrypted) will be accessible. You probably need to setup something to redirect traffic on port 80 to port 443.

Comment: @MarkB what would be the best way to implement this? htaccess? I can't seem to find one, Is there a tutorial I can follow to achieve this?

Comment: If you're using Apache then yes, do it in the Apache config. I haven't used Apache in so long I can't say what the best way would be.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit wet behind the ears, where can I find some guidance on doing this through Lightsail? @MarkB

Comment: Lightsail is just the computer you are running some software on. The technique to configure Apache on Lightsail should be no different than any other computer. Don't limit your search results by adding unnecessary search terms like "lightsail". Just search for something like "Configure Apache redirect HTTP to HTTPS" or "Apache redirect port 80 to 443"

Answer (score 0):

I didn't expect it to take so long as the TTL is set to 60 seconds. Everything is operational again, I hope my SSL is installed correctly.